# Does this argument that the cohomology group of a CW complex is the same as that of a large enough skeleton work?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes

Let $n \in \mathbb N$. Given that $H_n(X_q) \cong H_n(X)$ for all $q > n$, the UCT tells us that
\begin{align} 
H^n(X; G) &\cong \mathrm{Ext}(H_{n - 1}(X), G) \oplus \mathrm{Hom}(H_n(X), G) \\ 
&\cong \mathrm{Ext}(H_{n - 1}(X_q), G) \oplus \mathrm{Hom}(H_n(X_q), G) \cong H^n(X_q; G) 
\end{align}
for all $q > n$.

Does this work? I have my doubts about this argument because the splitting in the UCT is not natural, but one of my cohorts said that this is the way to think about it.

Comment: Sure, that works. In case you want a different approach: how do you know that $H_n(X_q) \cong H_n(X)$?

Comment: Because the image of any simplex lies in some skeleton.

Comment: How about using the cellular chain complex?

Comment: All I really know from the cellular chain complex (well, the LES of a pair that gives us the cellular chain complex) is that $H_n(X_q) \cong H_n(X_{q + 1})$ for $n \neq q, q - 1$.

Comment: The cellular chain complexes for $X$ and $X_q$ are the same in dimensions $q$ and below, because they have the same cells in those dimensions.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess that's a good point. And the differentials are the same, because the attaching maps are the same.